# cant ping docker container by name from host

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have many containers on my server, I need to access all containers by the name(not IP).
and of course, I can ping containers by IP address.
problem is I can't ping them by hostname or name.

also, I don't using docker-compose. I use docker file and docker restapi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option A: run a DNS proxy server container**

Here is a `DNS proxy server` project that can do this: https://github.com/mageddo/dns-proxy-server

First, you need to start the DNS proxy server:

```
docker run --rm --hostname dns.mageddo -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf defreitas/dns-proxy-server
```

Then, run a dummy container and assign it a `--hostname` for testing purpose:

```
docker run -d --hostname=this-can-be-resolved-from-host nginx
```

Finally, try to resolve/ping/curl the name you assigned to the nginx container in the previous step, from your host machine:

```
neo@neo-desktop:~$ nslookup this-can-be-resolved-from-host
Server:     172.17.0.4
Address:    172.17.0.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   this-can-be-resolved-from-host
Address: 172.17.0.3
Name:   this-can-be-resolved-from-host
Address: 172.17.0.3
```

```
neo@neo-desktop:~$ ping this-can-be-resolved-from-host
PING this-can-be-resolved-from-host (172.17.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
```

```
neo@neo-desktop:~$ curl this-can-be-resolved-from-host
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
[...]
```

---

**Option B: Run an injector that adds the container names directly in the `hosts` file, on the docker host:**
(solution found by the OP [@Tokyo Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9689465/tokyo-developer))

Here is a simple "etc/hosts" file injection tool: https://github.com/dvddarias/docker-hoster

Run the injector container:

```
docker run -d \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    -v /etc/hosts:/tmp/hosts \
    dvdarias/docker-hoster
```

Run a dummy container and assign it a `--hostname` for testing purpose:

```
docker run -d --hostname=this-can-be-resolved-from-host nginx
```

Try to resolve the `hostname` **AND** the `container name` assigned to the nginx container in the previous step, from your host machine:

```
nslookup this-can-be-resolved-from-host
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   this-can-be-resolved-from-host
Address: 172.17.0.3
```

```
nslookup keen_lamarr
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   keen_lamarr
Address: 172.17.0.3
```

Comment: of course, I used mageddo about half hour ago and i find it full of issues. but thank you for replying.

**SOLVED: I find "[docker-hoster][1]" more usefull and fastest solution**


  [1]: https://github.com/dvddarias/docker-hoster

Comment: Good point @TokyoDeveloper, I just tested it: looks cleaner and faster with only one thing to be aware of: if the container is killed, the `hosts` file on the host machine will be left in the last state that was configured. While this can seen as a expected behavior, on the other hand can be considered a _leftover_ on the host machine. Conversely, the proxy solution acts as an interceptor and leaves the host system in the initial state when stopped. I can add the solution that you found in an edit if you wish, for other people running into your question.

Comment: actually that s all i need . by the way thanks . yes do it please